# Key error with SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False with Flask_Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app running with `python 3.5.6 - flask_sqlalchemy 2.2 - sqlalchemy 1.1` with SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False .
Recently , after upgraded to `python 3.9.1 - flask_sqlalchemy 2.5 - sqlalchemy 2.3`  . The i face

```
Mar 30 06:25:46 myhost app [20986]: if self._echo_map[echo] <= logging.INFO and not self.logger.handlers:
Mar 30 06:25:46 myhost app [20986]:       KeyError: 'False'
```

Then when change `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False`  to `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` then it works ,
but it is not really a solution, because if the `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO =True` :

- It will print all the query, i can not debug any more
- Even in prod env, i have to turn `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True`. Does it slow down the api call ? (i guess yes)

Do you guys have any idea about this ?

Comment: Add one more check - if echo in self._echo_map:

Comment: If you remove SQLALCHEMY_ECHO in config file, sqlalchemy dont show sql commands in console.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]